# Cascading Template Use in mustache-express?

Tags: node.js, express, mustache

My intent is to define a page_layout template and a form template as well.  Within the route handler i was going to parse the inner (form) template and inject into the greater layout than return.

After several plot twists i'm able to use the response.app to get access to my mustache template engine and parse a view, but the HTML is getting escaped :(

```
let router = require('express').Router();
let mustache = require('mustache');
router.get('/plant', function(request,response) {
  response.app.render('plantForm', {pageTitle: "Plant"},function (err, html) {
    response.render ('layout', { pageContent : html});
    });
  });
```

yields the outer template with escaped html where I expect content:

```
             &lt;div class&#x3D;&quot;form-group&quot;&gt;
    &lt;label for&#x3D;&quot;plantNameInput&quot;&gt;Plant Type&lt;&#x2F;label&gt;
```

Perhaps I'm misusing the technology?

Answer (score 0):

From the Mustache documentation:

```
All variables are HTML escaped by default. If you want to return unescaped HTML, use the triple mustache: {{{name}}}.
```